# Recieving a 422 http error when trying to login using axios with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Hello I am trying to post login details to my back end using axios, when I try it on Postman it works fine but when I do it through my front end I receive error 422

I am using fast API as my backend, a colleague is building it not me

I am using React as my frontend

here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import'./login.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {username:'', password:''}
    this.handlechange = this.handlechange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  handlechange(e){
    this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value})
  }
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password};
      
    
    axios.post('https://fastapi-aadil.herokuapp.com/login,
        data, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
  ) 
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response);
  });
  }
  render()
```

the error I Receive

```
xhr.js:210 POST https://fastapi-aadil.herokuapp.com/login 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

I am not sure where I am doing it wrong I have tried and changed almost everything but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: Is this your own api you are using? Posting on the user resource in a REST API indicates creating a user ressource. Thats in sync with the Status Code of 422 which is generally used for validation errors. In short: The Api thinks you want to create a new user, but you don't provide all necessary fields.

Comment: Yes its my API, i was testing the signup method which takes the same body to test but i still receive the same error. I had updated it to login it was my fault but the error still the same 422

Comment: Can you post the implemenation of the API endpoint?

Comment: Or post what you use for postman.

Comment: @Aymanj Is there a specific reason to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` over `application/json` as request body content type? I will suggest an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` like this with axios. See below on how to use it with axios.

```js
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new URLSearchParams()
    params.append('username', this.state.username)
    params.append('password', this.state.password)
    
    axios.post(
        'https://fastapi-aadil.herokuapp.com/login',
        data, 
        { 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }
   ) 
   .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data)
   })
      .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tobi, you gave me a hint on why I'm receiving this error, its exactly what u said since I am using ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` as the content type. although I didn't use URLSearchParams(), I instead used qs according to axios docs ```import qs from 'qs';
const data = { 'bar': 123 };
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url,
};
axios(options);```  non-theless thanks for the help I will post my code next

Answer (score 0):

As @Tobi said in the previous answer that I can't use `x-www-form-urlencoded` I searched on axios docs on how to use it with react
it turned out we must use qs to stringify the data when making a post request.

and here is my code it worked fine.

```
 handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const values = {'username': this.state.username, 
    'password':this.state.password
  }
  const data = qs.stringify(values)
      
    
    axios.post('https://fastapi-aadil.herokuapp.com/login',
        data, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
  ) 
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response);
  });
```